# Make Mandrill dotnet use handlebars instead of mailchimp

Tags: .net, handlebars.js, mandrill

I have a question regarding this api wrapper for mandrill : https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet

I'm trying to use handlebars for one specific template this because it has an array of objects that need to be inserted into the template currently I am currently doing that with mergetags like this :

```
int i =0;
foreach (var object in model.Objects)
{
    email.AddRecipientVariable(email, "OBJECT" + i + "_NAME", object.Name);
    email.AddRecipientVariable(email, "OBJECT" + i + "_VALUE1", object.Value1);
}
```

which makes for giant email templates with *|OBJECT1_NAME|* *|OBJECT2_NAME|* all over the place and having to check each time if it exists
now with handlebars i should be able to do this:

```
 {{#each objects}}{{this.name}}{{/each}}
```

but i cannot seem to get mandrill to accept handlebars as merge language instead of the default mailchimp i've tried adding it to the header as so:

```
var email = new EmailMessage();
email.AddHeader("merge_language", "handlebars");
```

and as

```
email.AddMetaData("merge_language", "handlebars")
```

as specified here: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/105267476-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content#the-mandrill-api but neither seem to work.

So yeah how do i make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the API wrapper you are using, I think I found your problem:

Within the EmailMessage model (https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/2ce2105ad132bb1c869c7b32e4969827bab85180/src/Mandrill/Models/EmailMessage.cs) I found a public property merge_language and a static class "TemplateSyntax" that defines the const strings for MailChimp and Handlebars. Try setting the merge_language using the const string for Handlebars. This should do the trick :)

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use unreleased / pre release versions of mandrill dotnet so I am unable to use this since this has only been added last month and has not been released to nuget yet. Do you know of another way to achieve the result or am i out of luck ?